How to implement function for arbitrary primitive types in nostd
For an embedded project I want to implement something like:
      pub const fn from_argb<A, R, G, B>(a: A, r: R, g: G, b: B) -> Self {
        let value = (((a & 0xff) << 24) |
        ((r & 0xff) << 16) |
        ((g & 0xff) << 8)  |
        ((b & 0xff) << 0)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

This does not compile because the generics are not guaranteed to have operators &, | or <<.
How do I annotate all that so it compiles in nostd?

What counts as a primitive type? num_traits::int::PrimInt? Kind of seems like this particular example function only makes sense for u8 or u32 at best anyway (I’d write it fn(u8, u8, u8, u8) -> u32 and make the caller do as u8 – then implement it with u32::from_be_bytes).

Put bounds on your A, R, G and B traits that they each implement the necessary operators you are going to use, and possibly in combinations too since your
| operators are going to work with different traits pairwise.

@TanveerBadar Can you give an example for Bounds in const functions?

You cannot be generic and be const at the same time.

@ChayimFriedman I didn't know that. I guess my rust-fu still has a long way to go.
